Kobayashi-Nomizu "Foundations of differential geometry" on page 117 wrong?
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $G$ a Lie group and $P(M,G)$ a principal $G$-bundle and $\rho: G \to \GL(V)$ of $G$ a representation with $V$ finite-dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector space (where $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$) with inner product $\langle\cdot \, , \cdot \rangle_V$. Let $g$ be a metric in the associated vector bundle $E(M,V,G,P)$.
Now, in Kobayashi-Nomizu "Foundations of differential geometry" on page 117 it is stated the following:

The set
$$Q:= \{u \in P \, | \, g(u\xi,u\eta) = \langle\xi, \eta\rangle_V \ \forall \ \xi,\eta \in V \}$$
is a closed submanifold of $P$ and has a canonical structure as principal $H$-bundle over $M$, where
$$H := \rho^{-1}(O(V, \langle\cdot\, , \cdot\rangle_V)) = \{a \in G \ | \ \langle \rho(a)\xi, \rho(a)\eta\rangle_V = \langle\xi, \eta \rangle_V \ \forall \ \xi,\eta \in V\}.$$

I want to proof this fact and did the following:
It is clear that
$$Q\cdot h = Q$$
for all $h \in H$. Further it is clear that for $u,u' \in Q$ with $\pi(u) = \pi(u')$ and $u' = ug$ for some $g \in G$ it follows that $g \in H$.
Also $H$ is clearly a closed subgroup of $G$.
What is missing is that for all $x \in M$ there should be an open neighborhood $U \subseteq M$ of $x$ and a local section $\sigma: U \to P$ of $P$ with
$$\sigma(U) \subseteq Q.$$
Why should this exist? Why is even $Q \neq \emptyset$? Is this statement above even true?
In Kobayashi-Nomizu it is stated that it is "easy to verify".
I tried Gram-Schmidt but it didn't work:
If $G$ is extended by $\rho$ to the whole $\GL(V)$ then it should work by choosing an local orthonormal frame $(e_i)$ of $E$ and local section $\sigma$ of $P$ on $U$. Then $e_i(\pi(u)) = u\cdot f_i(u)$ for $u \in P$ for some $G$-equivariant  smooth $f_i: \pi^{-1}(U) \to V$ and $g(e_i,e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. Now choose a smooth function $b: U \to \GL(V)$ such that $b(x)^{-1} (f_1(\sigma(x)),...,f_n(\sigma(x)))$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ for all $x \in U$. Set $\tilde\sigma := \sigma\cdot b$ and $\tilde f_i = b(\cdot)^{-1}f_i$. Then $e_i = \tilde \sigma \cdot \tilde f_i$ and thus $g(e_i,e_j) = \delta_{ij} = \langle\tilde f_i,\tilde f_j \rangle_V$.
The problem: $b$ has image in $\GL(V)$ and not in $G$.
Also a simple example didn't work:
Take $M = P$, $G = 1$ and $V = \mathbb{R}$. Then $E = M \times \mathbb{R}$. Take the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}$. Take some positive smooth function $f: M \to (0,\infty)$ with $f(x) \neq 1$ for all $x \in M$ and define $g_x((x,s),(x,t)) := f(x)st$ for $x \in M$ and $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $g$ is a metric in $E$ and $Q = \emptyset$. So the above is not true.
What is wrong here? What am I missing? Is this an error in Kobayashi-Nomizu?
(See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5011091).

An 'erratum' in mathematical publishing is usually a document correcting errors, I think you mean to ask simply if this is an error.

@DavidRoberts Yes, I thought in Latin it just means error and it is the singular form of errata. I thought only errata is the page or document which lists the errors with corrections. But I will change it.

Well, maybe if there is only a single error to fix, the Latinists would be happier if one used 'erratum' rather than 'errata'. Though I just learned that 'erratum' is for when the mistake is the publisher's, and 'corrigendum' for when the mistake is due to the author(s): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erratum

I think the results in this section hold if $\rho \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a surjective submersion, in which case you can use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to get your section. Otherwise, the construction does not go through in general. Furthermore, the claim that a metric on the vector bundle associated to a principal bundle $P \to M$ over a paracompact manifold has a metric connection in $P$ also seems to be false. For example, take $P = M = V = \mathbb{R}$ and $g_x(v, w) = vw\exp(x)$.

@user527492 Do you know if this or a similar result also appear in other differential geometry texts? Maybe they have forgotten some assumptions? I only have the old edition and don't know if it maybe occurs in the errata of newer versions. It feels that it is quite unlikely that after 60 years there is still an error like this in a standard reference, so I am sceptical. Maybe I am missing something stupid.

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$I think the result is not true for arbitrary metrics. But it is true for a special class of metrics (if the following is correct!):
Write $O(V,\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle_V) =: O(V)$.
First observe that the space of inner products in $V$ can be identified with $O(V)\backslash{\GL(V)}$ by
$$O(V)\varphi \mapsto ((\xi,\eta)\mapsto \langle\varphi(\xi), \varphi(\eta)\rangle_V).$$
Define the fibre bundles $R(M,H\backslash G, G, P)$ and $S(M,O(V)\backslash GL(V), G, P)$, where $G$ acts on $H\backslash G$ by $g\cdot Hz := Hzg^{-1}$ and on $O(V)\backslash GL(V)$ by $g\cdot O(V)\varphi := O(V)\varphi\rho(g^{-1})$.
Now, a metric $g$ in $E$ is nothing but a section $g \in \Gamma(S)$ of $S$.
Let $\bar \rho: H\backslash G \to O(V)\backslash{\GL(V)}, Hz \mapsto O(V)\rho(z)$. Then the following proposition holds:

$Q\subseteq P$ is an embedded submanifold and $Q(M,H)$ a principal $H$-bundle (with the natural structure) if and only if $g \in (P\times_G \bar \rho)_* \Gamma(R)$. In this case the natural inclusion $\iota: Q(M,H) \to P(M,G)$ is a reduction.

This can be shown with the same idea as in the proof attempt in my question. But now it is guaranteed that the manipulation of the local section of $P$ works, since the elements are in $G$!
Alternatively, this proposition fits to the reduction theorem, which says, that sections of $R$ correspond $1:1$ to reduced subbundles (w.r.t. canonical inclusion) of $P$ (in Kobayashi–Nomizu it is Proposition 5.6 of chapter I). Note that in this case $Q$ is exactly the subbundle corresponding to the section $\tilde g \in \Gamma(R)$ with $g = (P\times_G \bar \rho)_* \tilde g$.

Now it is also clear why my simple example with $M=P$ and $G=1$ and $V= \mathbb{R}$ does not work: it is in that case $R = M$ and $S = M\times (0,\infty)$ and $P\times_G\bar\rho: R =M \to S = M \times (0,\infty), x \mapsto (x,1)$. It is $\Gamma(R) = \{\mathrm{id}_M\}$. By the proposition $Q$ is a reduced subbundle if and only if $g \in (P\times_G \bar \rho)_*\Gamma(R)$ if and only if $f \equiv 1$.

Further, the first part of the answer of @user527492 is a special case of this proposition:
in that case it is $\bar \rho: H\backslash G \to O(V)\backslash{\GL(V)}$ a $G$-equivariant diffeomorphism (since $\rho$ is assumed to be a surjective submersion and $H = \rho^{-1}(O(V))$ by definition). Therefore $P\times_G \bar \rho$ is an isomorphism of fibre bundles $R \to S$ and thus $\Gamma(S) = (P\times_G \bar \rho)_*\Gamma(R)$. Therefore there is no restriction on $g$ in this case and by the above proposition the result in @user527492's answer follows.

Then this would indeed be an erratum.

It may be helpful to compare this with Proposition 5.6 of I, which says that reduced $H$-subbundles $Q$ are in correspondence with global sections of the associated $G/H$-bundle.

Specifically, given such $g$, consider the preimage of the section $(P \times_G \overline{\rho})^{*}g$ under the projection $P \to P/H$, call this reduced subbundle $Q$. If $u \in Q$ and $p = \pi(u)$, then we may write $\sigma(p) = u 1_{G/H}$, so
$$g(u\xi, u\eta) = (P \times_G \overline{\rho})(u1_{G/H})
(u\xi, u\eta) = u\overline{\rho}(1_{G/H}) (u\xi,u\eta) = \langle \rho(1_{G})\xi, \rho(1_{G})\eta \rangle_V = \langle \xi, \eta \rangle_V,$$
which seems to yield a direct proof.

@user527492 Yes, indeed. I also thought about this reduction theorem but thought first that it is not immediate that this proposition follows. Now I see that it is indeed quite immediate, if one shows that $Q$ is the subbundle corresponding to the section of $R$. So, I can replace the "?" by a "." in the last sentence...

The results in this section hold if $\rho \colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is a surjective submersion, but do not hold in general otherwise. For what follows, write $\theta$ for the bundle metric.
For each $i, j \in [n]$, define $\theta^{ij} \colon P \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\theta^{ij}(u) = \theta_{\pi(u)}(u \cdot \mathbf{e}_i, u \cdot \mathbf{e}_j)$. This defines a smooth map $\Theta \colon P \to \mathrm{S}_n^+$, where $\mathrm{S}_n^+$ is the space of all positive-definite symmetric matrices. Then $Q = \Theta^{-1}\{\delta\}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the identity matrix.
In order to show that $Q$ is a smooth submanifold, it is enough to show that $\mathrm{d}\Theta_u \colon \mathrm{T}_uP \to \mathrm{T}_{\Theta(u)}\mathrm{S}^+_n$ is surjective for all $u \in P$. Note that $\mathrm{T}_{\Theta(u)} \mathrm{S}_n^+$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ dimensional, and is spanned by the vectors $\mathbf{F}_{k\ell} = \mathbf{E}_{k\ell} + \mathbf{E}_{\ell k}$, where $\mathbf{E}_{k \ell}$ is defined to be the matrix with a single one in the $k$th row and $\ell$th column and zeros everywhere else. For each $k, \ell \in [n]$, we will find some vector in $\mathrm{T}_uP$ which maps to $\mathbf{F}_{k\ell}$.
So, let $U \subseteq M$ be a trivializing open set containing $q =\pi(u)$ and $\psi \colon \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times G$ be an isomorphism; from this we obtain a section $\sigma \colon U \to \pi^{-1}(U)$ given by $\sigma(p) = \psi^{-1}(p, 1_{G})$. To take the derivative of $\Theta$ we may use the Leibniz rule, which can be justified as follows. Let $\overline{\Theta} = \Theta \circ \psi^{-1}$ and define $\widetilde{\Theta} \colon U \times (G \times G) \to \mathrm{S}^+_n$ by
$$
\widetilde{\Theta}^{ij} \big(p, (g_1, g_2)\big) = \theta_p\big(\sigma(p) \cdot \rho(g_1)\mathbf{e}_i, \sigma(p) \cdot \rho(g_2)\mathbf{e}_j\big).
$$
It follows that $\overline{\Theta} = \widetilde{\Theta} \circ \Delta$, where $\Delta \colon G \to G \times G$ is the diagonal map. Identifying $\mathrm{T}(U \times G \times G) \cong \mathrm{T}U \oplus  \mathrm{T}G \oplus \mathrm{T}G$, we have that for all $g \in G$ and $w \in \mathrm{T}_{g}G$,
$$
\mathrm{d}\overline{\Theta}^{ij}_{(q, g)}(0 \oplus w) = \mathrm{d}\widetilde{\Theta}^{ij}_{(q, g)}(0 \oplus w \oplus w) =  \mathrm{d}\widetilde{\Theta}^{ij}_{(q, g)}(0 \oplus w \oplus 0) +  \mathrm{d}\widetilde{\Theta}^{ij}_{(q, g)}(0 \oplus 0 \oplus w).  
$$
However, since the maps $T \mapsto \theta_q\big(\sigma(q) \cdot T\mathbf{e}_i, \sigma(q) \cdot \rho(g)\mathbf{e}_j\big)$ and $T \mapsto \theta_q\big(\sigma(q) \cdot \rho(g)\mathbf{e}_i, \sigma(q) \cdot T\mathbf{e}_j\big)$ are both linear, it follows from the chain rule that
$$
\mathrm{d}\overline{\Theta}^{ij}_{(q,g)}(0 \oplus w) = \theta_q\big(\sigma(q) \cdot \mathrm{d}\rho_g(w) \mathbf{e}_i, \sigma(q) \cdot \rho(g)\mathbf{e}_j\big) + \theta_q\big(\sigma(q) \cdot \rho(g)\mathbf{e}_i, \sigma(q) \cdot \mathrm{d}\rho_g(w)\mathbf{e}_j\big),
$$
so the Leibniz rule follows. Since $\theta_p$ is a metric and $\rho(g)\mathbf{e}_j \neq 0$, for any $k, \ell \in [n]$ there exists vectors $\mathbf{f}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{f}_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\theta_p\big( \sigma(q) \cdot \mathbf{f}_i, \sigma(q) \cdot \rho(g) \mathbf{e}_j\big) = \tfrac{1}{2}(\delta_{ik}\delta_{j\ell} + \delta_{i\ell}\delta_{jk})$. Furthermore, because $\rho$ is a submersion, there exists some $w \in \mathrm{T}_{g} G$ such that $\mathrm{d}\rho_g(w) = \mathbf{f}$. It follows that $\mathrm{d}\overline{\Theta}_{(q, g)}(0 \oplus w) = \mathbf{F}_{k\ell}$, so $\mathrm{d}\Theta_{u}$ is surjective.
Next, observe that $Q$ is $H$-invariant, since if $h \in H$ and $u \in P$, then
\begin{equation*}\tag{$\star$}
\theta^{ij}(uh) = \theta_{\pi(u)}(u \cdot \rho(h)\mathbf{e}_i, u \cdot \rho(h)\mathbf{e}_j) = \langle \rho(h)\mathbf{e}_i , \rho(h) \mathbf{e}_j \rangle = \delta_{ij},
\end{equation*}
since $\rho(h) \in \mathrm{O}(n)$. Hence, $uh \in Q$. On the other hand, if $u, u' \in Q$ are in the same fiber of $P$, then $u' = uh$ for some unique $h \in G$. Applying $(\star)$ shows that $h \in H$.
Finally, to show that $Q$ is a principal $H$-bundle, it is enough to establish that $\pi|_Q \colon Q \to M$ is surjective and $\mathrm{d}\pi_u \colon \mathrm{T}_uQ \to \mathrm{T}_{\pi(u)}M$ is surjective. Then $\pi|_Q$ will be a surjective submersion, admitting local sections. Given any $u \in P$, there exists some  $T \in \mathrm{GL}(n)$ such that $\sigma(q) \cdot T\mathbf{e}_i$ is an orthonormal basis with respect to $\theta_q$. Since $\rho$ is surjective, there exists some $g \in G$ such that $\rho(g) = T$. It follows that $ug$ is an element in the same fiber belonging to $Q$. Thus $\pi|_Q$ is surjective. To show that $\mathrm{d}\pi_u|_{\mathrm{T}_uQ}$ is surjective, observe that $\mathrm{T}_u Q = \ker \mathrm{d} \Theta_u$. Since $\mathrm{d}\overline{\Theta}_{(q,g)} \colon \mathrm{T}_{q} U \oplus   \mathrm{T}_{g} G \to \mathrm{T}_{\Theta(u)} \mathrm{S}^+_n$ restricts to a surjection on the second summand, the projection onto the first factor maps $\ker \mathrm{d}\overline{\Theta}_{(q,g)}$ onto $\mathrm{T}_q U$.

As discussed in a previous comment, the construction may fail if $\rho$ is not a surjective submersion. However, one may wonder if a reduced $H$-subbundle (obtained potentially through some other method) always exists. We show that this cannot be the case if $\rho$ is not a surjective submersion. Consider the principal $\mathrm{O}(1)$-bundle $\pi \colon \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ given by $z \mapsto z^2$ and the representation $\rho \colon \mathrm{O}(1) \to \mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
\rho(-1) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}; \quad 
\rho(+1) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $H = \{a \in \mathrm{O}(1) \mid \rho(a) \in \mathrm{O}(2)\}$ is trivial. Hence, the principal bundle can not possibly admit a reduction of the structure group to the trivial group, since there is no global section $\sigma \colon \mathbb{S}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$.

The first result also follows from the proposition in my answer (see my answer for details).
